# Automatically populate date in oracle table

Tags: oracle, time, timestamp

I have created a table in oracle XE, and I have a field with type date. I would like if possible when I insert a row, that it automatically fills that field with the current date from the system.

I am inserting the rows from the SQL prompt.

Thanks

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Here is how, you need to format your table properly:

```
create table test (first number
                   , second timestamp default systimestamp
                   , third varchar2(12));
```

And your default value is always current system time formatted as timestamp.

Comment: If the column has datatype of `timestamp` why not default to `systimestamp` rather than `sysdate`?

Comment: what is the difference? I use sysdate, if you can explain that would be great for me as well for Andan who asked the question

Comment: date (which is what `sysdate` returns) is only accurate to the nearest second, timestamp (returned by `systimestamp`) has greater precision (e.g. 1000'th of a second or better)

Comment: @ant I need updated_date and created_date to be automatically populated. like `timestamps` property in mongoose.
I need created_date to be populated when record is created and never change. and I want update_date to be set to the same value as created_date when record is first created. and then automatically update it when the record update (created_date should not update).
How can I achieve that in Oracle xe?

Answer (score 6):

change the field after creating the table

```
ALTER TABLE table MODIFY time_collumn TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or you could also use a trigger:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER date_trigger

BEFORE INSERT

ON table_name

REFERENCING NEW AS NEW

FOR EACH ROW

BEGIN

SELECT sysdate INTO :NEW.column_name FROM dual;

END;
```

Comment: This works better if you need to ensure that the timestamp is never entered manually. Although that case may be rare.

Answer (score 1):

The below snippet might be helpful if we forget to add the constraint while creating the table:

```
ALTER TABLE TABLE_NAME 
ADD CONSTRAINT CONSTRAINT_NAME
COLUMN_NAME DATA_TYPE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE;
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10300790/4040068 says that Oracle does not implement DEFAULTs as CONSTRAINTS. I’m on a really old Oracle version (11g) but a quick Google search also didn’t help in finding out if this is a new feature. Are you sure your `ADD CONSTRAINT` is for Oracle and not another DBMS?
Because in my case I get the error " ORA-01430: column being added already exists in table 01430. 00000 -  "column being added already exists in table"". Oracle tries to add a new column and not only a constraint.