# can we name a default constraint in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

In MS-SQL we can have the following constraint during table creation

```
create table test
(
  WarningEnabled bit NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_WarningEnabled   DEFAULT 1,
);
```

as we can see, i have given a name for Default constraint. IS it possible to do this in oracle

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  Oracle does not implement a default value as a constraint so there is no way to name the constraint.  You also won't be able to see the default constraint in the data dictionary views that relate to constraints (i.e. `ALL_CONSTRAINTS`, `DBA_CONSTRAINTS`, `USER_CONSTRAINTS`).  You'd have to query the `DATA_DEFAULT` column from `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS` (or `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` or `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` depending on your privileges and the column you're interested in).