# Create table constraint confused on syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, relational-database, sqlplus

creating a table called funtom_payroll but I need to write a constraint to show the date the payroll was entered, this is in the payroll_date

```
create table Funtom_payroll
(
 payroll_ID    number(3),
 payroll_Emp      number(3),
 payroll_Standard   number(8,2),
 payroll_Overtime   number(8,2),
 payroll_Pension      number(8,2),
 payroll_Timesheet   number(3),
 payroll_Date      date,
 constraint payroll_pk primary key(payroll_ID),
 constraint payroll_fk1 foreign key (payroll_Emp)
   references funtom_employee(Emp_ID),
 constraint payroll_fk2 foreign key (payroll_Timesheet)
   references funtom_Timesheet( timesheet_id),
"    CODE FOR HERE   "
 );
```

Comment: Please elaborate... what do you need? Do you need the system to add a timestamp automatically? If so then Kenny is right, this is a duplicate. But you are talking about "constraint" - do you really need a constraint, and if so of what type? Or was that just the wrong word?

Comment: so there is an column called payroll_date in the funtom_payroll table and in the comments of the data dictionary it says.. "the date the payroll record was entered."

Answer (score 0):

As Kenney mentioned, this is very close to [Automatically populate date in oracle table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2033063/automatically-populate-date-in-oracle-table), just with `DATE` instead of `TIMESTAMP`.

You just need to add "default sysdate" to the `CREATE` statment... no need to make a constraint here.
`PAYROLL_DATE DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,`